# How to save CNN model configuration to file

Tags: keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I want to save my CNN model configuration (kernel sizes, activations, filters, etc) to txt file. By using "summary" I only get layers input, output and params, but I need more information.

I tried the following functions:

```
# large dictionary with all information, but have a lot of noise info
config = model.get_config()
# same dictionary, but converted to string
summaryJson = str(model.to_json())
```

All this solutions don't give me the most important parameters. So I found this solution that seems to give all that I need, but it doesn't work:

```
from keras_diagram import ascii
summary = asc(model)
```

But it gives me following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Activation' object has no attribute 'inbound_nodes'
```

This is my last layers:

```
...
hid = Conv2D(128, kernel_size=5, strides=1, padding='same')(hid)
hid = BatchNormalization(momentum=0.9)(hid)
hid = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1)(hid)

hid = Conv2D(3, kernel_size=5, strides=1, padding="same")(hid)
out = Activation("tanh")(hid)

model = Model(input_layer, out)
summary = ascii(model)
```

Do you know what to do?

Comment: The json configuration contains all the parameters that are required to reconstruct the model (except weights), so I fon't understand when you say the contrary.

Comment: I don't want to reconstruct model, I just want to save the configuration because I'll do testes with different kernel sizes, and so on. I need to log all the configurations that I tested

Comment: get_config() and to_json() do exactly that.

Comment: It's not human readable. It's confusing and if someone who don't understand how to code, can't read and understand it.

Comment: Binary is not human readable, JSON was made exactly to be human readable. Maybe you just need to write your own format by getting the configuration of each layer manually.